# Is SSIS the way to achieve this functionality?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a manual process that needs to be automated. Below are the steps outlined. Is SSIS the correct way to achieve all the below mentioned steps? Especially the result to CSV, zip and email steps? Can this be done using inbuilt sql server scheduler?

1. Connect to SQL Server: DARVIN,51401
2. Open SQL Query:  o:\Status Report.sql
3. Chose database: AdventureWorks
4. In the menu bar above choose ‘Tools’, then ‘Options’.
5. When the pop-up appears, choose the tab named ‘Results’ and choose Results output format of Comma Delimited (CSV).  Clikd the ‘Apply’ then the ‘OK’ button.
6. Execute the query
7. Instruct where to save the file, You can save these in O:\Reports       File name format is: day^_^Report TSP MM-DD-YY
8. Let the query run 15-25 minutes.
9. When the query is complete, open the folder that you save the report in, right click on the report title and compress to a zip file. (right click, Send To Compressed (zipped) Folder) When this has been completed.
10. Copy the saved file and put into: O:\zippedFiles\
11. Email:  support@adventureworks.com to let them know that you 
    have placed a zip file at: O:\zippedFiles\

Comment: I need to create zip file and put CSV file into it.

Comment: I think, zipping could be achieved using execute process task (assuming that something like winzip is already installed on that machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exacly what SSIS is for : automating data transfer processes.

The only stp that might cause you problems is the zipping part. You can use a third party library, and do a custom script task that will achieve what you want. You will have to do some Vb.Net (or C#) to achieve that part.

The rest of what you want is pretty straightforward in SSIS.